# Best practice with lookup table implementation to improve performance

Tags: java, mysql, database, hibernate, primary-key

I was wondering what is the best way to create a lookup table.
For example I have a table `missionProfile` with one field (primary key) String `idMissionProfile` and one field `note`. All my values must be different each other.
But with this approach all the tables linked to `missionProfile` have the whole string key as foreign key and I think that it takes up more memory and requires more time to write the whole string than one `Integer` primary key.
But if I use an integer primary key I have to check ever if the field missionProfile exists before create it, because the key is incremental and it is possible a duplicate value of my field.
In a big database,with your experience, it is better use String or check always if the field exists and then write into database?
Thank you

example

MissionProfile:

```
idMissionProfile
------------------------------------------
FIRST_OIL_CHANGE_SAMPLE_&_PARAMETERS_RESET  
NEDC    
VEHICLE_TRANSFER
```

or

```
idMissionProfile   MissionProfile
-------------------------------------------
1                  FIRST_OIL_CHANGE_SAMPLE_&_PARAMETERS_RESET   
2                  NEDC 
3                  VEHICLE_TRANSFER
```

So in my Acquisition

```
idAcquisition id_MissionProfile
---------------------------------
1             1
2             2
3             2
```

otherwise I would have

```
idAcquisition id_MissionProfile
---------------------------------
1             FIRST_OIL_CHANGE_SAMPLE_&_PARAMETERS_RESET
2             NEDC
3             NEDC
```

The second approach seems better but when I add a new mission profile I have to check if exists, instead in the first approach it doesn't add a new string value if exists because it is the key.
This is a simple case, but if I have a primary key composed by several columns?
I'm mapping an excel file into database therefore I need to chooice the best approach to improve my performance

With incremental id I have:

```
MissionProfile missionProfile=null;
        if ((value=actualRowValues.get(ExcelMappingCoordinate.missionProfile.getCoordinate()+index))!=null){
            missionProfile= missionProfileServices.findByMissionProfile(value);
            //TODO se esiste allora carica quello che esiste altrimenti lo crea
            if (missionProfile == null){
                missionProfile= new MissionProfile();
                missionProfile.setMissionProfile(value);
                missionProfileServices.create(missionProfile);
        }
```

with key-value I have

```
MissionProfile missionProfile=new MissionProfile();
if ((value=actualRowValues.get(ExcelMappingCoordinate.missionProfile.getCoordinate()+index))!=null){
    missionProfile.setMissionProfile(value);
    missionProfileServices.create(missionProfile);
}
```

Comment: I do not really understand your question! If you use a string value as a key, then don't you need to check if that value exists before you use it? With an auto_increment integer type field, it is guaranteed that the key will be unique.

Comment: Maybe I didn't explain enough fine. All my values must be different each other, so if I store the value as primary key when I call the save method it doesn't add the value if it exists. If I store integer primary key and my value I have to check if exists.

Comment: If you use an auto_increment field as a primary key (or UUID as indicated by Neville in his answer), then the key's value is determined by mysql when you insert the record into the table.

Comment: I updated my question with an example

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're mixing up a whole bunch of things in this question. I'm not entirely sure I've understood what you're asking - a schema or even better a SQLFiddle would be great.

The first is "does a string take more space than an Integer?". The answer is yes, but it doesn't matter on modern hardware unless you're working at the very extremes of size, performance or scalability.

The second is "how should I generate my primary key?". This is a [surprisingly complex](http://www.agiledata.org/essays/keys.html) question; but pretty much everyone agrees that your primary key should be either "natural" (an attribute of the domain entity that is guaranteed unique and will never change), or an entirely meaningless thing like an auto-incrementing integer or GUID.

Reading between the lines of your question, it appears that your primary key for the lookup table has some kind of meaning because you're using it to check whether a value exists. This is a bad idea, because it means that you can never change that value without checking every related entity.

For instance, if you have an "employees" table and a "department" table, like so:

EMPLOYEES

```
EmployID  Name  Department    LeavingDate
------------------------------------------
1        Fred   HR            NULL
2        Angie  HR            1 Jan 2010
3        Bert   IT            NULL
```

DEPARTMENTS

```
DepartmentID     Name
------------------------------------------------ 
HR               HR Department
IT               IT Department
```

If the HR department changes its name to "PEOPLE" on 1 Jan 2016, what do you do with Angie? She left at a time when the department was called HR, so you can't really change it to PEOPLE. But you don't want to check for people who left when updating the name of the HR department.

It's much neater to have a meaningless key. That way, you can build a "name history" logic in Departments, without having to affect all the tables that link to it.

EMPLOYEES

```
EmployID  Name  Department    LeavingDate
------------------------------------------
1        Fred   1             NULL
2        Angie  1             1 Jan 2010
3        Bert   2             NULL
```

DEPARTMENTS

```
DepartmentID     Name                ValidFrom   ValidUntil
-----------------------------------------------------------
1                HR Department       1/1/1990    1/1/2016
1                People Department   1/1/2016    NULL
2                IT Department       1/1/1990    NULL
```

The third question I think you're asking is "should I even create a lookup table, or should I use attributes with inherent meanings?" This is especially important when importing from Excel.

The formal answer is to [normalize your data schema](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization), and to only worry about performance if you have an actual, measurable problem. This point is typically at the tens or hundreds of million records on decent hardware.

The more pragmatic answer is that it depends on how you intend to use the data.

If you consistently have to replace `FIRST_OIL_CHANGE_SAMPLE_&_PARAMETERS_RESET` with a more user-friendly string, I'd create a lookup table with an auto-incrementing primary key.

If there is business logic involved - `FIRST_OIL_CHANGE_SAMPLE_&_PARAMETERS_RESET` records are treated differently to `VEHICLE_TRANSFER` records, I'd use an auto-incrementing integer. This reduces the risk of typos, and allows you to add logic flags to the look up table.

If, however, you're just reading this column back out, with no logic or substitution, I'd just read that value straight into the table...

Comment: But with an auto-incrementing key it is possible to have the same value of my field for several row, therefore to avoid this I have to check if a value exists befor try to add to table. All this control can decrease my software performance?